# Python-Pandas- To get the latest record based on the Level Change

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, group-by

Requirement is to get the latest record where there is a change of level happened.
Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
         2,2,2,2,
         3,3,3,3],
  'Month': ['01-09-2020','01-10-2020','01-11-2020','01-12-2020','01-01-2021','01-02-2021','01-03-2021','01-04-2021',
            '01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-04-2020',
            '01-01-2021','01-02-2021','01-03-2021','01-04-2021'],
  'Level': [66,66,66,65,65,65,42,32,
            42,42,41,41,
            65,64,64,64],
  'Grade': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
            2,2,2,2,
            2,2,2,1],
  'Flag_Level': ['Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',
                 'N','N','N','N',
                 'Y','Y','Y','Y']
})
```

df:output:

```
    ID  Month   Level   Grade   Flag_Level
0   1   01-09-2020  66  1        Y
1   1   01-10-2020  66  1        Y
2   1   01-11-2020  66  1        Y
3   1   01-12-2020  65  1        Y
4   1   01-01-2021  65  1        Y
5   1   01-02-2021  65  1        Y
6   1   01-03-2021  42  1        Y
7   1   01-04-2021  32  1        Y
8   2   01-01-2020  42  2        N
9   2   01-02-2020  42  2        N
10  2   01-03-2020  41  2        N
11  2   01-04-2020  41  2        N
12  3   01-01-2021  65  2        Y
13  3   01-02-2021  64  2        Y
14  3   01-03-2021  64  2        Y
15  3   01-04-2021  64  1        Y
```

**Explanation of the columns from dataframe: df:**

ID: Each ID will have multiple records as per month (eg: 1 has 6 records (I.E. 6 months), 2 has 4 records ..)
Level : denotes the level of ID in each month and so as Grade
Flag_Level : denotes if there is any change in the level then denoted as Y else N. For record 1,3 we see a change in Level column hence Y and for record 2 no change in the level column.

**Tried Code :**

```
df_filtered = df[
  ( df.Level < df.groupby('ID').Level.shift(1) )
]
```

Here 64 level is greater than 65 level and so .on

After executing the above code:

ACTUAL Output is:

df_filtered:

```
    ID  Month   Level   Grade   Flag_Level
3   1   01-12-2020  65  1         Y
6   1   01-03-2021  42  1         Y
7   1   01-04-2021  32  1         Y
10  2   01-03-2020  41  2         N
13  3   01-02-2021  64  2         Y
```

**EXPECTED** output is  as below:

i.e. to get only the latest Month record of which the level change has happened
In this case Record 1 (above has 3 entries o/p),the latest change record for the level change should be available i.e. only the
7th record of Month : 01-04-2021 - and 32 level  ..Like below.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
    ID  Month   Level   Grade   Flag_Level

7   1   01-04-2021  32  1          Y
10  2   01-03-2020  41  2          N
13  3   01-02-2021  64  2          Y
```

Comment: What if the level for id=1 goes `1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2` or `1,1,2,2,3,3`?

Comment: Firstly there will not be any decrease i.e. 1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2. And incase any also And we need to consider the latest level only i.e. 2  the latest  record is from which period onwards start and its difference till date.

Comment: As the main idea is to check the latest level  change  from when it has started and till date

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question, and replace the images with formatted text of the code or data.  I don't and won't visit random image sharing sites.  Please read; [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Just add `.groupby('ID').last()`?

Comment: If the Month format is in YYYY-MM-DD does the result vary ? Because i tried with YYYY-MM-DD and is not expected .But with DD-MM-YYYY it is as expected? How can be dealt with YYYY-MM-DD formats?                                https://trinket.io/python3/3126bf278f

Comment: All that matters is the order in the data frame. Its not taking the last month, it's not reading the month at all. ***It's just taking the last row.***  Regardless of how the data is ordered. 
 If, however, you need to sort the data by date, you need either YYYY-MM-DD formatting, or, better still, an actual datetime64 datatype. Then you can apply the sort. I'll write a demo, but please stop changing the scope of this single question; asking about sorting, datatypes, etc, should really have been a new question (you're not limited to just one question). - https://trinket.io/python3/8ea1014d62

Comment: I also just noticed that you're using a non-standard datetime format of `%d-%m-%Y`, so you may want this: `df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: @MatBailie  ,Without > or < in code how can we get the latest record .As there is a scenario that i see , for same ID 1 has two levels 63 and 2 here i want to get the latest record which is 2 because after 63 it has changed to 2 (< or > in code doesn't work as it has nothing do with these greater or less) and with respective 2 the minimum month.(Same condition like the earlier) .. Since related to the same  requirement and another scenario putting the comment here.

Comment: `last()` doesn't check anything other than the position in the dataframe. It literally picks the last row. ***You*** are responsible for having ***sorted*** the dataframe before hand. Be that by `id`, a `datetime`, be that ascending or descending, whatever. It literally takes the row that is last in the dataframe and down a not care ***at all*** about the values in the rows. That's exactly what my answer's demo is to show; the behaviour before and after calling `sort_values()` is different, and that to adequately sort the `Month` column, it had to convert away from the arbitrary string format.

Comment: If you're actually talking about the identification of when there's a new group, just change `<` to "not equals" `!=`? (For example; if you want to identify when the value changes, rather then when it goes down.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your final output should be, or even precisely what filtering you want to apply, but this code filters to rows where `Level` has decreased, then takes the last such row per `ID`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
         2,2,2,2,
         3,3,3,3],
  'Month': ['01-09-2020','01-10-2020','01-11-2020','01-12-2020','01-01-2021','01-02-2021','01-03-2021','01-04-2021',
            '01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-04-2020',
            '01-01-2021','01-02-2021','01-03-2021','01-04-2021'],
  'Level': [66,66,66,65,65,65,42,32,
            42,42,41,41,
            65,64,64,64],
  'Grade': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
            2,2,2,2,
            2,2,2,1],
  'Flag_Level': ['Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',
                 'N','N','N','N',
                 'Y','Y','Y','Y']
})

df_filtered = df[
  ( df.Level < df.groupby('ID').Level.shift(1) )
].groupby('ID').last()

print(df_filtered)
```

https://trinket.io/python3/3126bf278f

***EDIT:*** Dealing with out-of-order data, and datatype, conversions...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
  'ID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
         2,2,2,2,
         3,3,3,3],
  'Month': ['01-01-2021','01-02-2021','01-03-2021','01-04-2021','01-09-2020','01-11-2020','01-10-2020','01-12-2020',
            '01-01-2020','01-02-2020','01-03-2020','01-04-2020',
            '01-01-2021','01-02-2021','01-03-2021','01-04-2021'],
  'Level': [65,65,42,32,66,66,66,65,
            42,42,41,41,
            65,64,64,64],
  'Grade': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
            2,2,2,2,
            2,2,2,1],
  'Flag_Level': ['Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y',
                 'N','N','N','N',
                 'Y','Y','Y','Y']
})

print()
print('Non-Date Ordered...')
print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
print()
print(df)

print()
print(df.dtypes)

print()
print(
  df[ df.Level < df.groupby('ID').Level.shift(1) ].groupby('ID').last()
)

df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Month'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
df['Flag_Level'] = df['Flag_Level'].astype('category')

print()
print('Changed Datatypes')
print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')
print()
print(df.dtypes)
print()
print(df)

df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Month']).reset_index(drop=True) # dropping the index is optional

print()
print('Date Ordered...')
print('~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~')

print()
print(df)

print()
print(
  df[ df.Level < df.groupby('ID').Level.shift(1) ].groupby('ID').last()
)
```

https://trinket.io/python3/7c44cb99d9